# Jquery change text field not working

Tags: jquery, input, jquery-plugins

I have trying to do this jquery that the selected items will be shown in text field but its not working,it works fine if it is used in div that is in place of input text using of div but it does not work in this following code as text field

```
 <html>
<head>
 <style>
  div {
   color: red;
   }
  </style>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <select name="sweets" multiple="multiple">
   <option>Chocolate</option>
   <option selected="selected">Candy</option>
   <option>Taffy</option>
   <option selected="selected">Caramel</option>
   <option>Fudge</option>
   </select>
   <input type="text" name="fname">
   <script>
   $( "select" )
   .change(function () {
    var str = "";
   $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
   str += $( this ).text() + " ";
    });
    $( "fname" ).text( str );
    })
    .change();
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

1) change from `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`

to `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`

2) Put your javascript code into

```
$(function({
  // your JS code
}));
```

3) Change from  `$( "fname" ).text( str );`to `$('input[name=fname').val(str);`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L6kskouo/)**

Answer (score 0):

Give the input an id attribute and use the id selector like:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" id="myInput">

$("#myInput").val(str);
```

"fname" is not an element so you can't use an element selector with it.

Comment: Why add an id when you can select the input by name? No extra markup needed

Answer (score 0):

try val instead of text like

$( "fname" ).val( str );

Comment: This would not work because fname is not an element.

Answer (score 0):

There was mistake in the way you have been using jquery here is jsfiddle. 
[Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/qgsb8x6h/)

You have not used `$(document).ready()` and besides you have even not assigned ID and class through which you can access elements. Hope this helps :)